# Convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^2_+=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\text{ }x\geq 0,y\geq 0 \}$, $a,b,r\in \mathbb{R}$, $a,r>0$, $b\geq 0$. Put: $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+|\text{ }y\leq ax^2+bx-r\}$$

Is the set $A$ convex?

Comment: Try to draw a picture. It becomes immediate that $A$ is either empty, or else it is not convex. Now formalize this intuition by constructing two points in $A$ such that the cord joining them does not lie entirely in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is not convex. The polynomial $y=ax^2+bx-r$ has exactly two real roots one positive and one negative. Name the positive root as $x_0$. Therefore since the points $P_1=(x_0,0)$ and $P_2=(2x_0, 3ax_0^2+bx_0)$ are in $A$ and the interconnecting line is not, so $A$ is not convex.